# Passing function through Switch Route component

Tags: reactjs, function, routes, switch-statement

I want to build an app, which collects input information from sub-components and lift this information up to my main App component. I am using Switch with multiple Route to navigate through my questionnaire. I am able to pass variables and functions through my app until the <Switch> statement.
My problem: how do I pass a function or variable into my <Route> component.

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
      date: new Date(),
      machineid: null,
    };

  handleChangeMachine(event) {
    const machineid_temp = event.target.value;
    this.setState({machineid: machineid_temp})
    console.log(machineid_temp)
  }

  render(){
    return (
    <div className="page">
      <Router>
        <Header testvalue="this is working"/>
        <Switch testvalues="this is working">
          <Route testvalues="this is not working" path="/" exact component={Landingpage}/>
          <Route path="/survey" component={Survey}/>
          <Route path="/kontakt" component={Kontakt}/>
          <Route path="/question_one" handleChangeMachine={this.handleChangeMachine}  component={question_one}/> {/* This is not working */}
          <Route path="/question_two" component={question_two}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

In this case the function handleChangeMachine isn't properly passed to the component question_one. Has anyone an idea about how I can solve it? I've tried every thing I understood as a React-beginner.

Comment: There is no such property `handleChangeMachine` that `Route` would accept.  [Route](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) only accepts. You should pass handler function to your component, rather than `Route`. `<Route component={<YourComponent onChange={this.handleChangeMachine} />} />`

Comment: could you please check your package.json and tell me weach version of react-router-dom do you use ?

Comment: @ldruskis it depends of react-router-dom versions !!!

Comment: @idurskis: if i change the Route like u suggested it tells me: "question_one is defnied but never used" and therefore will not be rendered

Comment: "react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0","react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using React-router@v5, you can write your route as follow:

```
<Route path="/question_one">
  <QuestionOne handleChangeMachine={this.handleChangeMachine.bind(this)}
</Route>
```

Note that `question_one` isn't a correct component name.

Or even :

```
<Route
  path="/question_one"
  render={({ match }) => {
    // Do whatever you want with the match...
    return <QuestionOne handleChangeMachine={this.handleChangeMachine.bind(this)} />;
  }}
/>
```

You can check [the documentation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) for more information.

Here is [a repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-nlrdbh).

Comment: You miss the binding he use class components ^^

Comment: thank you for clarification, but the first example throws an error for me which says that </Route> is an expected token and the second example still remains with "question_one is an un-used variable"

Comment: @Borni.Mr Yep thx I added it

Comment: @danmae Well this is working perfectly on the Stackblitz I added to my answer, can you show your full code or a reproducible example so we can see what you are doing wrong please ? But as I said,  `question_one` isn't a valid component name. Write it as I did : `QuestionOne` (So you need to rename it in the file where you are exporting it)

Comment: I renamed my component and tried the first line again and now it works perfectly fine, that you very much. I am a little sad that i dont know what went wrong the first time but now i know how i should pass functions to my components :) thanks

Comment: @danmae Well You're welcome :) For further explanation : firstly you were trying to pass you function to the component `Route` which is different then yours. It does not handle this props so you had an error. And secondly you had to rename your component so React can do its thing properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```js
class App extends Component {
    state = {
      date: new Date(),
      machineid: null,
    };

  handleChangeMachine(event) {
    const machineid_temp = event.target.value;
    this.setState({machineid: machineid_temp})
    console.log(machineid_temp)
  }

  render(){
    return (
    <div className="page">
      <Router>
        <Header testvalue="this is working"/>
        <Switch testvalues="this is working">
          <Route testvalues="this is not working" path="/" exact component={Landingpage}/>
          <Route path="/survey" component={Survey}/>
          <Route path="/kontakt" component={Kontakt}/>
          <Route path="/question_one">
          <question_one handleChangeMachine={this.handleChangeMachine.bind(this)} /> // rename component with UpperCase and without "_"
          </Route>
          <Route path="/question_two" component={question_two}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: still the same error as suggested in the first answer. it says: src\App.js
  Line 7:8:  'question_one' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
(Line:7:8) is where i am importing it like this: import question_one from './components/questionaire/question_one';

Comment: please try to add codesandbox for your work to see what's going wrong ?